# How do I get an HTML Element in node.js express?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I am building an app in node.js ran into a problem because I couldn't get an `HTMLElement`

Is it possible to do something like

```js
document.querySelector("#div")
```

Or

```js
document.getElememtById("div")
```

But in Node.js express?

My code:

Index.js:

```js
const express = require('express');

// App set up
const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile("Public/index.html", {root: __dirname});
})
app.use(express.static('Public'));

// Listen
app.listen(3000, () => console.log('started'));
```

/index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="div"> Hello world! </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking additional questions.

Comment: On the client or server side?

Comment: On the client .

Comment: You say "On the client" but in the question you say "But in Node.js express" which is on the server...

Comment: I want to get an HTML element in index.js file

Comment: Sorry but I am new to express